# Differential equation exercise

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I have the following exercise:

$$(2x-y)e^{\frac{x}{y}}dx + (y+xe^{\frac{x}{y}})dy=0$$

After some substitution and putting $v=\frac{x}{y}$ i have the following equation:

$$\frac{1-2v}{2v^2+e^{-v}}dv=\frac1ydy$$

but i don't know how continue. Is it correct? Thanks.

Comment: Its correct, for $|y| > \epsilon >0 $ of course

Comment: Applying the fundamental theorem of calculus would be next. The [solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+f%28v%29+dv+%3D+1%2Fy+dy) will not always have a neat explicit form $y=y(x)$.

Comment: @user170231 ok. but the solution is $y^2+2x^2+e^\frac xy=c$ and i don't know hot to reach this result.

Comment: That "solution" doesn't satisfy the given equation. Denote it by $f$, and see for yourself that$$f(x,y)=c\implies\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\,dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\,dy\neq\text{your ODE}$$Rather, it satisfies [this ODE](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+y*%284+x+y+%2B+e%5E%28x%2Fy%29%29+dx+%2B+%282+y%5E3+-+x+e%5E%28x%2Fy%29%29+dy+%3D+0).

Comment: @user170231 yes. I find the same ODE. thanks for your help.